# Create an array using indexes/values of another array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab

In MATLAB its simple:

```
 array1 = [5,6,7,8];
 array2 = array1(2:3);
```

OUTPUT:

```
  array2 = [6,7]
```

How do I do this in CSharp?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you want C# you should so some C# attempts

Comment: `var array2 = array1.Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray();`

Comment: In MATLAB, does changing the values in `array2` also change the values in the array it was created from?

Comment: Might have been a bad example. What about array2 = array1(132:279)

I dont want to have to write them all individually

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in c# start with index 0, so doing this will give you the same output as your example.

```
array1 = [5,6,7,8];
array2 = new Array[array1[1],array1[2]]
```

OUTPUT

```
array2 = [6,7]
```

EDIT because of this comment:
Might have been a bad example. What about array2 = array1(132:279) I dont want to have to write them all individually – lsama

An easy way to do it is with a method like this.

```
array1 = [5,6,7,8];
array2 = new Array();

private void getThisIndexes(int firstIndex, int lastIndex){
  for(int i=0; i < array1.length; i++){
    if(i < firstIndex&& i >= lastIndex){
      array2.add(array1[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might have been a bad example. What about array2 = array1(132:279)

I dont want to have to write them all individually